# When does a set of vector become a field?

Tags: vector-fields, geometric-algebras

Let us say that I have a set $\mathbb{V}$ of multivectors of $Cl_4(\mathbb{C})$. They are expressed as follows:

$$
\mathbf{v}_1=R_1+ t_1 \mathbf{e}_0 + x_1 \mathbf{e}_1 +y_1 \mathbf{e}_2 +z_1 \mathbf{e}_3 \\
\vdots\\
\mathbf{v}_n=R_n+ t_n \mathbf{e}_0 + x_n \mathbf{e}_1 +y_n \mathbf{e}_2 +z_n \mathbf{e}_3
$$

I 'visualize' each element of $\mathbb{V}$ as assigning a scalar value $R_i$ to each point in space-time. Furthermore, 'metric information' is encoded in the basis $\{\mathbf{e}_0,\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2,\mathbf{e}_3\}$. Consequently, since it appears to have all the required ingredients, $\mathbb{V}$ reminds me of a field in physics.

---

Fields in physics are usually defined as $R:(x,y,z,t)\to \mathbb{R}$, and an integral over such a field is usually defined as $I=\int R\sqrt{g}d^4x$.

---

Is $\mathbb{V}$ analogous to a field?

I am trying to find the logical equivalent to $I=\int R\sqrt{g}d^4x$ but instead using $\mathbb{V}$ as a starting point.

Specifically, how do I sum over all elements of $\mathbb{V}$ to obtain a field integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your construction is over-specified.  You want 4 parameters to parameterize the space time volume.  For example, suppose that you have a vector function of time and space coordinates that spans the integration volume of interest
$$\mathbf{u} = t \mathbf{e}_0 + x \mathbf{e}_1 + y \mathbf{e}_2 + z \mathbf{e}_3,$$
then the natural way to express the differential volume element is just
$$   \sqrt{g} d^4 x =   \left( { \frac{\partial {\mathbf{u}}}{\partial {t}} dt } \right) \wedge   \left( { \frac{\partial {\mathbf{u}}}{\partial {x}} dx } \right) \wedge   \left( { \frac{\partial {\mathbf{u}}}{\partial {y}} dy } \right) \wedge   \left( { \frac{\partial {\mathbf{u}}}{\partial {z}} dz } \right)   =   \mathbf{e}_0 \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 \mathbf{e}_3 dt dx dy dz.$$
I've included your $ \sqrt{g} $ term on the left hand side since the wedge product of the differentials implicitly builds in the Jacobian structure that I assume this represents.

Comment: Hello, is the $\sqrt{g}$ term the square root of the determinant of the spacetime metric in your construction?